# SSRS: Arguement <arguement> cannot be converted to type 'Date'

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, expression

I'm trying to convert the following SQL into a default expression in a parameter in SSRS.

I'm expecting to get the start date of the month and year that's passed in as the parameter.

```
SET @startDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@startMonth AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATETIME)), 0);
SET @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) + 1, @startDate);
```

> An error occurred during local report processing. The DefaultValue
>   expression for the reporting parameter 'startDate' contains an error:
>   Argument 'Date1' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.

**Current expression:**

```
=DATEADD("d", -DATEPART("dw", DATEADD("m", DATEDIFF("m", 0, CDate(CStr(Parameters!startMonth.Value) + "/1/" + CStr(Parameters!year.Value))), 0)) + 1, DATEADD("m", DATEDIFF("m", 0, CDate(CStr(Parameters!startMonth.Value) + "/1/" + CStr(Parameters!year.Value))), 0))
```

**The values for the parameters:**

@year = '2016' INT

@startMonth = '8' INT

I've tried all kinds of different ways of changing the format but keep getting the same error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The start date of the month?

Comment: @Ciaran yes, I'm passing in a month and year and expect to get the start date. I believe the problem specifically lies here: `DATEDIFF("m", 0, CDate(CStr(Parameters!startMonth.Value) + "/1/" + CStr(Parameters!year.Value)))`

Comment: I don't think you can do that cascading parameters will only work with data sets providing the defaults. you can certianly code it as =DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Month.Value,1) but it won't dynamically change.

Comment: `DATEDIFF("m", 0, CDate(CStr(Parameters!startMonth.Value) + "/1/" + CStr(Parameters!year.Value)))` what is the purpose of doing this? And for `DATEDIFF`, you have to specify both two parameters for date, **0** is invalid, but I still did not see any purpose of doing this date difference. And did you switch the parameter order?